# Populate ComboBox with Row values in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, list, combobox, userform

I am not able to populate a combobox with cell values stores in a single row, horizontally. It works when they are placed vertically, though.

ComboBox.List ("A1:A10") works but ComboBox.List("A1:J1") doesn't. It only displays the first value in the latter case.

I would be grateful if someone could help me out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Transpose` your array:

```
 ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(Sheet1.Range("A1:J1").Value)
```

p.s.: the correct syntax from a column is:

```
ComboBox1.List = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10").Value
```